# How to extend QGIS Graphical Modeler with Python Scripts

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to extract lat longs from my centroids, then feed the lat longs to the Google distance matrix API using another python script. I exported the graphical model as a python script:

```
##Drive Time=name
##GridSpacingInMeters=number1000
##Extent=extent
##CentroidsWGS84=output vector
##GridWGS84=output vector
outputs_QGISVECTORGRID_1=processing.runalg('qgis:vectorgrid', Extent,GridSpacingInMeters,GridSpacingInMeters,0,None)
outputs_QGISREPROJECTLAYER_1=processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', outputs_QGISVECTORGRID_1['OUTPUT'],'EPSG:4326',GridWGS84)
outputs_QGISPOLYGONCENTROIDS_1=processing.runalg('qgis:polygoncentroids', outputs_QGISREPROJECTLAYER_1['OUTPUT'],None)
outputs_QGISEXPORTADDGEOMETRYCOLUMNS_1=processing.runalg('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', outputs_QGISPOLYGONCENTROIDS_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'],0,CentroidsWGS84)
```

Then I added more lines to the above to create a list of the coordinates, but I'm getting a *IndexError: list index out of range*

```
name = 'CentroidsWGS84'
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]
features = layer.getFeatures()
attributes = []
coords = []

for feature in features:
    atributes.append(feature.attributes())

for attribute in attributes:
    coords.append(attribute[5:7])
```

I suspect this is because the layers that I'm creating on the graphical modeler is not created yet. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access the layer through the variable outputs_QGISPOLYGONCENTROIDS_1 which is a dictionary (holding the path to the shapefile from your processing step) and the QgsVectorLayer Class:

```
##Drive Time=name
##GridSpacingInMeters=number1000
##Extent=extent
##CentroidsWGS84=output vector
##GridWGS84=output vector
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

outputs_QGISVECTORGRID_1=processing.runalg('qgis:vectorgrid',  Extent,GridSpacingInMeters,GridSpacingInMeters,0,None)
outputs_QGISREPROJECTLAYER_1=processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', outputs_QGISVECTORGRID_1['OUTPUT'],'EPSG:4326',GridWGS84)
outputs_QGISPOLYGONCENTROIDS_1=processing.runalg('qgis:polygoncentroids', outputs_QGISREPROJECTLAYER_1['OUTPUT'],None)
outputs_QGISEXPORTADDGEOMETRYCOLUMNS_1=processing.runalg('qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns', outputs_QGISPOLYGONCENTROIDS_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'],0,CentroidsWGS84)

data_source = outputs_QGISPOLYGONCENTROIDS_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'] #access the datasource
layer = QgsVectorLayer(data_source, 'centroids', 'ogr')
#here comes your code...
```